# The mysterious box: The First Clue

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, story, knowledge, history

It was a normal day when I got the box came in the post. I opened it and found a handful of objects inside. I picked out a piece of paper and on it was a riddle:

> The next clue lies within the top rung of me
>   I am controlled by the 6
>   The key to me is found within this box
>   I will lead to the richest treasure you will ever know
>   Use the key, and you will gain the knowledge to solve this

Fishing through the box, John also found a pendant:

[image: The star of David]

He also found a small object. It was a transparent hollow tube with a piece of paper inside. The paper had written on it `you`. John turned over the tube and found in small bumps the letters `7nAZqPqlz1M`

Where is the next clue, and in which country can it be found?

---

<sub>*[Next Clue --->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70145/50691)*</sub>

Comment: Does this mean that Part 2 is coming soon? This series looks interesting!

Comment: yes, Part 2 will come soon

Comment: @El-Guest [Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70145/50691) is here now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of @jafe's answer, it could very well be that the next clue is in the

> Church of the Holy Sepulchre, Jerusalem, Israel. (Specifically, the top rung of the Immovable Ladder at the Church).

In the last line, @jafe has discovered

> .. you... tube... 7nAZqPqlz1M... which seems to imply [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nAZqPqlz1M). The video discusses the [Immovable Ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immovable_Ladder) which is currently found under the window of the Church of the Holy Sepulchre. If @jafe is correct in identifying the text on the pendant as reading Zion, this clue combined with the Star of David-shaped pendant seems to imply travelling to the Jewish State, Israel.

Answer (score 0):

Partial

> ... you... tube... 7nAZqPqlz1M...
>  Wild guess, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nAZqPqlz1M ?
>
>  The text on the pendant says "Zion", I think.

Comment: [Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70145/50691) is here now!